# cfspreadsheet combine two sheets with one on top?

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

Is it possible to easily combine two xlsx spreadsheets? I basically just want to take sheet1 from spreadsheet1.xlsx and put it at the top of sheet1 on spreadsheet2.xlsx

Comment: What do you mean by "on top of"?  Please provide an example. Also what version of CF are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you’ll need to read each spreadsheet into a query object and then perform a UNION on those two queries to  join them (one on top of the other), and then write out that new object into a new spreadsheet.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfspreadsheet.html